# ng-model for select box in not reflecting back in link function in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've a select element in directive's template file. If I select any other value it is not reflecting back in link function of the directive. But it shows in the view file when I'm printing it.

In the following, I'm showing the excerpt of the code for readability purpose:

**product.tpl.html**

```
<form ng-submit="update_product()" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <select  name="product" ng-model="product" 
    ng-options="product.name for product in products track by product._id">
    <option ng-hide="true"></option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" ng-hide="tab.active == 2">Update</button>
</form>
```

**directive**

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('product', product);

product.$inject = ['productService'];

function product(productService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    link: link,
    templateUrl: 'product.tpl.html',
  };

  function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.product = {};

    scope.update_product = update_product;

    productService.get_products().then(
      function (response) {
        scope.products = response;
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );

    function update_product() {
      console.log(scope.product); // prints undefined
    }

  }
}
```

**products data**

```
{
  "products":[
    {
      "_id":"LINUX_VM",
      "name":"LINUX OPERATING SYSTEMS",
      "supported_features":[
        "File System",
        "Linux Kernel",
        "SCSI Devices",
        "Security"
      ],
      "models":[
        {
          "id":"UBUNTU_DESKTOP",
          "name":"Ubuntu Desktop OS"
        },
        {
          "id":"UBUNTU_SERVER",
          "name":"Ubuntu Server OS"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce the issue in [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/78e3yJijXV0rIbfum1qb?p=preview) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need an `ng-change` on your `select`.

```
<form ng-submit="submit_product()" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <select  name="product" ng-model="product" 
    ng-options="product.name for product in products track by product._id"
    ng-change="update_product()">
    <option ng-hide="true"></option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" ng-hide="tab.active == 2">Update</button>
</form>
```

Note that I have changed your ng-submit to another function, you could keep it as you had if but I'm assuming you want to use your button to submit (and do another logic).

Also, you don't need this: `scope.update_product = update_product;`

Just do this:

```
scope.update_product = function () {
  console.log(scope.product); // prints undefined
}
```

If this doesn't answer your question, then you should provide a plunkr as mentioned by Pankaj Parkar.